# What is the best way to contact a moderator about a user?

Tags: support, ethics

I suspect a user is cheating. He's cheated in the past but I don't want to get into it here. Instead I want to contact a moderator about this. What is the best way to go about this? Should I send an email to the SO team or flag a post in question? Though it isn't about any one post but instead a pattern of behavior. I want to provide some fairly detailed findings, at least the best findings a regular user can provide. Also, do moderators have the ability to look into who is casting votes?

Comment: Flag one of his posts with the "Other" reason and explain what you think.

Comment: E-Mailing `team@stackoverflow` will work as well

Comment: Post it here. No seriously, irregular behavior and other oddities have been brought to Meta before. It allows us (the community) to learn from it...best case is that you suddenly have a horde of users stomping through SO looking for that pattern of behavior. **Edit:** It will also allow the user to explain himself and the result of the investigation will be visible to all (learning once more).

Comment: eh, I'd rather not publicly expose my suspicions about the user. I went ahead emailed the SO team.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can (as mentioned in the comments):

- Flag one of his posts for a moderator, and explain.
- Email team@stackoverflow.com
- <strike>Make a Meta post about it (it's been done before)</strike> <-- **Don't do this**

Comment: #1 and #2 are perfect, but for #3, **we ask that people do not create meta posts about *specific users*.** Meta is for broad classes of actions that could help lots of people... so the question is correct as written.

Comment: well, you can make a meta post as per above asking about the general *situation*. Just don't make a meta post full of axe grinding about Alan Smithee, Esquire, Stack Overflow User of Ill Repute. (also the @ is not required here since there's nobody else you could be replying to in this case.)

Comment: I'm amazed that it didn't edit the `@` out.

Comment: *do I smell a feature request?*