# Serial downvoting -- is it detected, and what is the threshold?

Tags: support, status-completed, serial-voting, scripts

So various posts, such as [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim) suggest that there is a script that detects serial downvoting.

Over the course of a few minutes, 36 of my questions and answers were downvoted (and it seems that the process is still going on)

How many downvotes are needed to trigger the serial downvoting logic?

[image: I wish I were making this up]

Comment: Far fewer than 36 will trigger the detection (assuming they're by the same user, of course). Give it a day or two, and come back if you're not made whole by then.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta is the detection script run daily or at lower frequency?

Comment: Daily is what I understand.

Comment: I'm sort of amazed anyone thought _36_ downvotes wouldn't be noticed as abuse, even if there was no automatic method to address the problem. I hope you at least get some pity upvotes out of this :)

Comment: @agf I wish i were making this up -- posted a screenshot because its absolutely hilarious

Comment: Originally voted down because the answer to this seemed entirely obvious. Reversed now because I would ___freak out___ if I saw that on my rep tab even though the total amount of rep isn't that much.

Comment: @agf I take pity on the type of person who would actually go through and downvote more than two questions ...

Comment: Moderators can [see suspicious voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98507/should-community-flag-serial-voting/98514#98514) and, if I'm not mistaken, even *some* details, like how many times users voted one another. If you have a high suspicion about who downvoted you, then maybe you can [ask a moderator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104375/what-is-the-best-way-to-contact-a-moderator-about-a-user) to have a look. Just an automatic reversal without a message from a moderator doesn't seem satisfying to me in this case.

Comment: @sbi who do you think was responsible for this?

Comment: @FooBah - indeed, what a sad practice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

36 is more than enough (the actual number needed hasn't been revealed), but it is run on some kind of schedule so you might want to give it more time.

Comment: "the actual number needed hasn't been revealed" <-- is that the case because people would game the system if it was revealed?

Comment: exactly, then they'd go downvote up to that limit.

Comment: Do you know how frequently the detection script is run?  Is it daily or at lower frequency?

Comment: No idea on the frequency.

Comment: There has been no official word on when the fraud script runs.  I was serial-downvoted a few months ago and I vaguely recall the rep being returned *before* midnight GMT.

Comment: So it appears that the downvotes were finally removed ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the downvotes have been detected and rolled back and the offending user has been dealt with accordingly.

Comment: They still show up (its on stackoverflow) as of 9:03 AM Eastern Time

Comment: @FooBah  Ah ok...I was looking at the graph. Just wait 24hrs or so and they'll be nullified. I had the same thing two or three weeks back (6 serial downvotes) and they were all cancelled out around 24hrs later.

Comment: I tried to remove the status-completed tag but it says only moderators can do that ...

Comment: @Kev, no need for Naming & Shaming here, but: has the offending user indeed been notified, or was that an assumption? Or is that even part of the automated "undo" nowadays?

Comment: @Arjan - that's a human process.

Comment: ...still curious: was that done in this case? (If you can tell, but I think that diamond gives you Super Powers, @Kev!)

Comment: It's starting to happen again, so I really want to know who is downvoting!

Comment: @Arjan - sorry, can't really say much more other than appropriate action was take and the wheels are back on the wagon again.

Comment: @Kev Can “appropriate action” ever mean anything more than merely reversing the downvotes once detected? I ask because I just got hit with a buttload of them. This happens to me now and then (can’t imagine why :), but this time seems worse than the routine hate-spree.