# Bring back a penalty for downvoting questions

Tags: discussion

I understand that the downvoting penalty for questions was eliminated.  However, now people seem to use it for vengeance downvoting.

After having tried it for some time, should the downvoting penalty be reintroduced?

Comment: Show some proof for the vengeance downvoting, or it didn't happen.  Note that revenge votes are routinely removed via the nightly fraud detection scripts.

Comment: I discussed this in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108029/serial-downvoting-is-it-detected-and-what-is-the-threshold lightly, but summary is that the first things to be downvoted were the questions .. also its been 14 hours without resolution.  When are these nightly fraud scripts run?  And were these downvotes deemed fraud?

Comment: Looked at some of your questions, I don't see where this is happening.

Comment: Removing the cost for casting downvotes on questions was one of the best changes ever. People need to become more active in separating the good from the bad.  The vengeance downvotes are no issue if you wait a bit, or report them here.

Comment: @robert, he already showed proof, as per his link.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I don't think the revenge downvoting on his account was in any way linked by the change to question downvoting. If it were, the person would have just downvoted all his questions. Instead, they downvoted some but not all of his questions and a lot of his answers. I think instead, that backs up what Robert is saying -- "People who get mad enough to go on a downvoting spree do not care about losing a little rep; consequently, the 1 rep requirement is not a deterrent."

Comment: @agf, valid point on the 'question' point, but Robert didn't address that in his comment, he just said 'Show some proof for the vengeance downvoting'.  Everyone here knows that vengeance downvoting occasionally happens, so why does every poster need to show proof?

Comment: @LanceRoberts It's not explicit, but I interpreted his comment as "Show some proof for the vengeance downvoting [as a result of there not being a cost to downvoting questions]." I think that was implicit because that's the subject of this question. I agree it wouldn't make sense as a general statement, and I doubt he meant it that way.

Comment: This is proof. He doesn't like free down-votes, so those that don't agree down-vote him. Isn't down-voting for bad un-realted questions? I've put a lot of effort on questions (that WERE related) only to have them down-voted by a question natzi. People come and see -1, so they down-vote. More negatives, more mob mentality. Isn't Stack Exchange about quality answers, not questions? A question can be clarified. The asker cares. An answerer writes something quick and doesn't always care. Yet down-voting answers cost rep, but not questions. It really pisses mee off. It should cost something.

Comment: @Luke Downvotes on meta just mean you disagree.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @Troyen, ok got it. Thank you for the clarification. I've just seen this on other SE sites. As a new user I've put a lot of effort into my questions only to have them down-voted immediately and loose 2 rep points. When a question gets below 0 people tend to continue neg-reping the question because someone else did. Because of this it makes me delete my question so I don't loose even more rep. It really upsets me. Makes me not want to ask questions at all... Which is a shame because SE is awesome for getting quick concise answers. As an asker I care very much about my questions.

Comment: @slhck: After one of my comments on an SO question, which was well intened additional information, caused the asker to go on a rant swearing at me and all SO users that commented or downvoted his question. The question was closed and all offensive comments removed. 10 minutes later 6 of my 7 questions were downvoted within the same minute. The tool has not detected that and the downvotes still exist. I assume 6 questions within the same minute is not detected by the tool.

Comment: @slhck: I think downvoting question of the same user pofile within the same minute should impose a 1 minute down-vote timeout penalty, similar to comments where it is 5 seconds. As you keep downvoting the same user profiles questions continuesly after the penalty, the penalty should keep increasing each time. My point is that some prevention mechanis must exist and not just leave it up to a tool to deal with consequences only. the tool obviously cannot detect small sets of down-votes like 6 questions within a minute as that could be concidered normal.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl 6 questions within a minute are not normal. The detection runs over night (GMT) and so you might want to wait a little. If it's not reversed, flag for moderator attention and we'll check it out.

Comment: I couldn't agree any less as there are just a lot of idiots.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, the 1 reputation downvote "penalty" is not a penalty; it is a payment.  In exchange for this payment, you are accorded the privilege of removing 2 rep from the poster of an answer, and reducing the score of the post by 1.

This one rep cost was removed for questions to encourage downvoting on questions, since people seldom downvoted questions prior to the rep requirement being removed.  This is working; marginal questions are now downvoted much more regularly.

This downvoting of marginal questions is a key component of the automatic question asking ban.  Reinstating the 1 rep cost for downvoting questions would have an adverse effect on this ban.

Finally, vengeance downvoting was a problem before the 1 rep requirement was removed.  People who get mad enough to go on a downvoting spree do not care about losing a little rep; consequently, the 1 rep requirement is not a deterrent.