# OMG Stack Overflow is being perceived as a helpful environment

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

Just look at this great example of how nice and helpful Stack Overflow is getting these days!

> [Delete a member array correctly in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18336163/46642)

This is obviously a neophyte learning C++ that lacks knowledge in a particular C++ concept. How do we reward him? Here's a sample of the feedback we've provided so far:

- a bunch of seemingly correct answers, one as a comment, one accepted;
- a comment showing where to find better learning material;
- a comment warning against bad practices and suggesting a safer alternative;
- a comment suggesting an even simpler and safer alternative.

Hopefully no one flagged them. This question was not closed and the user resorted to thanking other users in comments.

> Thank you for the advice. I'm using VC11, but this code is very old.

Does anyone seriously think the OP is going to post here again?

Why do we accept this as OK?

Comment: Owww my sides...

Comment: Uhh... I don't see anything wrong with that question...? I feel like I'm missing something really obvious :P

Comment: Those... *Bastards!*

Comment: Okay, joking aside, what exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: I like the sarcasm tags in the edit, too bad it doesn't change the formatting...

Comment: +1 because I read another question, and I convinced myself that I had to write a comment in order to be able to up-vote the question.

Comment: Okay, so you're talking about the Related sidebar, but what about it? I can't tell what you're talking about; please just stop being so vague :P

Comment: @apaul34208 - Thanks for pointing that out.  I was really confused. I also feel like something really *really* bad is about to happen after reading that C++ post. :D  Everybody be safe!

Comment: I've been noticing this too over the past few days and it's really unfortunate. I've brought this up in my Meta question: ["Could we please be a bit meaner to new users?"](http://goo.gl/SsAhv).

Comment: I think it's time to censor this. I'm all for free speech and all, but we just can't have this sort of *off-message* post hanging around here. (I can't wait until someone quotes this out of context! When it happens, I win Teh Intarwebz!)

Comment: Related: [Why do we let hostile users dictate the perception of Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191089)

Comment: OMG. Like, sometimes you guys are nice, but sometimes you are mean. I'm like, so confused right now.

Comment: This question worked because all the answers were wrong at first.  SO users read questions to be entertained.

Comment: It's utter horse#! that this should be closed while http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191089 shouldn't.

Answer (score 11):

This is a rant about something no one ever rants about. I wanted to challenge the notion that it is fine-ish to drop individual data points as individual questions here on meta and then launch a discussion about policy off of such individual data points.

This is my data point. There are many like it, but this one is mine. My data point is my best friend. It is my life. Erm, ok, maybe my data point doesn't play such an important role in my life.

In hindsight it seems to me that I was way too subtle in expressing my idea through this parody question. I apologise for any headless chickens that resulted from that.

---

<sub>No animals were harmed in the making of this answer.</sub>

Comment: Honestly, the "sarcasm" tags confused me more than anything. It looks like initial reading of the question was correct. Then I saw that the last two questions were marked as sarcastic, and started to question my initial impression. But maybe I'm weird. I *love* subtle irony.

Comment: Qualitative judgments about questions don't translate well to quantitative analysis.  If anyone *did* analyze a statistically significant subset of questions a link them here, I'd wager no readers would follow suit.  Hence, the use of examples instead.  "This matches a trend I've seen, let's discuss whether anyone else has seen it and if it's a problem" is the only realistic way to go in cases without objective metrics that can be pulled from questions in an automatic way.

Comment: No animals may have been harmed in the making of the answer, but they were harmed in the *reading* of it! ;)