# Is it bad to answer a question you know to be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, answers, off-topic

If someone asks a question that is overly broad or possibly opinionated, but you think you could give a useful answer to the asker and help them out a bit, is it bad to answer the question even if you know it will most likely be closed?

On one hand it helps the person better have a grasp of the question they want to ask (maybe answer a broad question by skimming the surface of all the things they need to be thinking about to answer their question, and it could help them ask a more useful question).

On the other hand it may reward the user for incorrect behavior, and be seen by outsiders as the correct way to ask a question.

So what do you guys think, is there ever a time when answering a question you know to be off-topic could be beneficial?

Comment: Related:[Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions)

Comment: You can go ahead and help, but you should be prepared to lose rep when the question is removed.

Comment: @random man something about the search here I always look for the question before I ask it and never find it, sure enough someone has asked the exact question.

Comment: If anyone is going to downvote this. Think. That means you _agree_ with answering those kinds of questions.

Comment: @nhahtdh or gain when I vote on them _hehehe_