# Five answers downvoted, without any comment

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, specific-question, down-votes

Me and 4 others answered this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081760/php-form-validation-gives-parse-error
(Note: the question deleted)

You can see that all of them downvoted, this is not the case, but the downvoter should provided a correct answer or provided a comment for one answer at least.

I knew downvoting is also important but providing correct answer is also very important in order to distinguish between correct and incorrect answers.

I hope some one help us, why all answers are downvoted without any comments or a correct answer. Currently, one answer is also accepted with had two downvotes.

Comment: Votes are anonymous, so unfortunately there's nothing much we can do about that.

Comment: @hims056: I am asking for a guide, someone who can tell those people why? is this a correct behavior? this issue related to managing this community and educating users not leave a question with bad answers, I am sure the person who downvoted can provide correct answer, I will thank him/her if did that.

Comment: Really, I agree with @hims056 here. As it seems, currently you are both asking for a correct answer and ranting about the downvoting nature in SO. Unfortunately, the first one is OT and the second one is a rule set by TPTB which you can't alone change by this post. So it's a pity you can't really do anything about it. BDW, I did not downvote you, rather upvoted because I believe there should be a comment before downvoting.

Comment: People usually tend to do this if the question was bad. They do not want you to answer bad questions. It encourages people to ask them. The question you provided had multiple downvotes, and it was off-topic.

Comment: Your answer is just a piece of code (whether or not it is correct is not the point). A good answer should provide an explanation or at least some tips on how the problem is solved. That said, it's strange that every single answer got downvoted.

Comment: @JoshC: I agree with you, but I saw many times that someone wrote in the comment: please delete your answer!

Comment: @hims056:  Now I see why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @Mistu4u: I am not looking for the persons who downvoted, its just nothing to look for, but the case is some how strange, a question with 5 answer (all had downvote) :)

Comment: @JasonOOO, Ya, I know and it's really appreciating how you took the step forward to post it to meta.

Comment: Five wrong answers to a poor question in a tag that's popular with junior developers doesn't strike me as unusual or surprising or some type of conspiracy.

Comment: Thanks for comments and answers, I posted this question for other users so that they can read and understand why :)

Comment: @CarlVeazey: lol :) what was wrong? can you tell me please?

Comment: @JasonOOO I barely know any PHP - all I'm saying is, based on experience in tags with similar problems as PHP, that if the answers were all wrong, it wouldn't be the first time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**People usually tend to do this if the question itself was bad.**

It's not good to answer bad questions, as this encourages people to ask them. The question you provided had multiple downvotes and was off-topic.

You didn't necessarily do anything wrong to receive those downvotes. Just avoid answering these types of questions. We cannot control who downvotes what, nor do people have to disclose why they are downvoting - as voting is completely anonymous.

**Downvoting is inevitable.**

---

**Related, see:** [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions)

Comment: Ok so, I liked this answer, so that other users that complained about downvote in the comment can see this post and understand, But I don't know what I did wrong ?

Comment: @JasonOOO: sometimes nothing, other times it is warranted.  In this case, it was most likely that it was because you answered an off-topic question, which is frowned upon by other as it appears that you are attempting to "milk" reputation from bad questions and also gives a signal that these sorts of questions are acceptable.  Maybe the downvoter just hates everyone related to the PHP tag at all, you never know.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: yes I realized this, and this is a good reason, but why the question not marked as off-topic or poor quality?

Comment: @JasonOOO: because people who answer generally don't vote to close or flag as off-topic, as they want to get reputation for accepted answer and/or upvotes.

Comment: @JasonOOO there are numerous questions on meta about the scary size of close voting queue - questions tends to stay open for long before they gets their review. That does not mean they are any good.

Comment: Wait, we can downvote because we don't like PHP? brb, have 80k rep to waste.

Answer (score 13):

The downvoter has no obligation to do anything. While admittedly it's nice and recommended to leave a comment explaining the issues with a post, this is not a requirement. Nor is leaving an answer, if you feel one of the answers given is not up to scratch.

In all honesty, there is nothing that can be nor should be done. If you feel that the answers are correct, leave them in place and move on.

Comment: I agree with this if there is at least one correct answer, I will probably do same and upvote the correct one, so that everyone can understand and recognize it, but when all answers are bad, so I have to provide a comment or a correct answer

Comment: All answers by @Bart regarding downvoted posts, declined flags, rejected edits end with *move on*. :)

Comment: Move on @hims056. Move on..... ;)

Comment: This is something I can't understand. If _commenting_ is not necessary, people start downvoting randomly. Ya, I know -1 is added to the downvoter for downvotiong an answer, but there is no rep loss in downvoting a question. It delivers unethical behavior.

Comment: @Mistu4u it would be nice to leave a comment, but it's no requirement. And if you wonder whether nor not it should be, please read through the tons of proposals and discussions on that topic. And then there is the revenge that pretty regularly is the result of explaining your downvotes. Ah, if only everything were perfect.

Comment: Ya, the _revenge_ thing makes sense. You earned a +1 :-)

Answer (score 7):

According to Jeff's answer [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006):

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> •not closed as a duplicate
>   •has a score of 0 or less
>   •is not locked
>   •has no answers with a score > 0
>   •has no accepted answer
>   •has no pending reopen votes
>   •has not been edited in the past 9 days

such questions are deleted.

So answering bad questions makes them harder to delete, if the answers are upvoted. Many people downvote answers to the questions that should not be answered to help that script to run without admin intervention.

Comment: `•has no accepted answer` yes this condition is not met! very good point :)

Comment: The downvotes could be made before the answer was accepted.

Comment: I meant if you want to delete this question, there is one answer that accepted so that this keeps the bad question on  the site.