# Answer showing "deleted by owner" when in fact it wasn't (well, not really)

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

OK, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19877829/447356): (10K only)

> [image]

The time of deletion of the answer is exactly the time of deletion of the question. The answer was deleted by its author once **but then undeleted** so by the time the question got deleted, the answer was there visible to all and undeleted. It can be seen in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19877863/revisions):

> [image]

It should show just "deleted 22 hours ago", just like on [this other deleted question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14610701/447356):

> [image]

What made me find that bug is [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204794/do-i-deserve-downvoting-for-answering-spoon-feeding-answers?noredirect=1#comment657419_204794), I was about to reply "Sure, you deleted it yourself" then noticed the oddity.

Comment: @animuson nice, can't believe it didn't get any attention since then! :(