# Off-topic questions - users breaching the rules still gain reputation off them

Tags: discussion, reputation, off-topic

Please take a look at this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897100/android-class-for-convert-string-to-phonetic/19897188#19897188.

It's clearly off-topic as it's a request for a recommendation of an external library. I voted to close the question and put a comment to OP. OP replied to my comment but still left the question.

Then another user put an answer. I put the comment for the answer as well but the answer stayed and was later accepted.

Moreover, both the question and answer were upvoted once.

I downvoted both the question and answer as there was no response from OP and answerer.

Now, the rep changes were:

- OP better of by 5 rep (+5 upvote, -2 downvote, 2 accepted an answer).
- Answerer better of by 23 (+10 upvote, -2 downvote, 15 accepted answer).
- me down by 1 (-1 downvote on answer)

The question was later put on hold but it doesn't change the rep gains and losses.

I'm not complaining about my lost rep. I just feel that the reward for asking and answering off-topic questions exists in the system. That gives a wrong  indication of hat behaviour is desired in SO.

Maybe when a question is put on hold for off-topic reasons, the reputation gains (only gains) should be reversed?

UPDATE

Aziz Shaikh has a valid point that the rep changes will be reversed once the question is closed and deleted (see [the answer below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/206926/165773)). The problem is, with the way closing queue is going, that may take very long (up to forever).

Comment: I think this is a good related thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions?rq=1 If people would follow it, the issue would go away.

Comment: The thing is though, it takes 5 downvotes to cancel one upvote...

Comment: Yeah, that's true reputation-wise. However, negative post rating should be a clear message indicating that the question or answer is not welcome...

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that the question you linked is actually off-topic. It doesn't ask for a link or how to find a library; it asks if there's a class in Android that will do something. It's no difference than asking if there's a class in the .NET framework for doing something. There's no request for a third-party library, no request for a link to an external resource, or anything else like that in the question. (The answer, on the other hand, is nothing but two links with no other useful information, and I'd have downvoted it for that reason.)

Comment: @KenWhite In this case, what would be the answer? "Yes, there is, but it's 3rd party"?

Comment: "`Try to search about Soundex. Try this link.`" is more of a comment anyways rather than an answer.

Comment: I didn't say it was a good question, or that it should be answered. I simply don't agree with it being a request for a product recommendation or external link. It's a vague question that shows no effort, and I would have voted to close it for that reason, and downvoted. The answer I would have downvoted (as I just did) because it has no content that would be meaningful if the external links aren't available. (I've also posted a comment to that question, BTW.)

Comment: It's wrong to penalize an answerer for giving a good answer to an inappropriate question.  Votes on answers should be based on content.  Downvote the question if you don't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to disagree because a closed (on-hold) question can still be edited to make it appropriate for Stack Exchange.

Questions can be put on hold for duplicates too. Dupes are allowed as long as they are marked as such (and closed). Users should be able to retain their reps in this case too.

However, when a question gets deleted then reps should be retracted (which is the current behavior).

Comment: True, I didn't think about editing questions on hold. That seems to happen rarely though.

Comment: Even for rare cases, I believe the suitable action is to wait for post deletion (by users having that privilege).

Comment: If only the close queue was shorter...

Comment: I wish for that too.

Comment: Rep is not lost from deleted questions in all circumstances; see [Deleted posts should not influence reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124754) for some details.