# Is it bad form to flag a question AND answer it?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I see a question I know isn't appropriate as asked (ie, its an opinion question, open ended, etc), so I flag it. But then I can't help answering it anyway.

Is that bad form?

How will flagging *and* answering a question affect my reputation?

Comment: Personally, I would just give hint/tips (and sometime direction) as comment to let OP knows that his question is not appropriate to be answered. But I guess answering it wouldn't hurt anyone too.

Comment: If you don't care about rep, or your content may be deleted along with the question, then go ahead. In a case or two, I answer + cast close vote on a bad question just because I like to answer it.

Comment: how would flagging + answering affect reputation?

Comment: "BAD QUESTION! BAD DOG!!" ... "EHH.. OK HERE YOU GO TAKE IT ANYWAAAY"

Comment: Like no one has ever done that before. :)

Comment: @JBCP - they are separate things. flagging can't affect rep

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is bad form. Please don't answer questions that are off-topic or otherwise inappropriate. Simply put, answering bad questions encourages users to ask more bad questions. It perpetuates a cycle of bad questions.

In short every time someone answers a bad question a unicorn [gets sent to the glue factory...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_glue)

---

For possible effects on reputation see: [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions)