# Should lecturing be allowed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

I've been finding Stack Overflow an indispensable tool, but I've noticed that too many (in my opinion) answerers take the opportunity to deliver a lecture on what is (in their opinion, but usually not admitted) the right way to do things, even though that's not what the question asked, or is only artificially or tangentially related to it.

Such answers get heavily voted and commented on, and generate largely subjective discussion that it's easy to be drawn into, but SO doesn't really seem the place for such discussions. Or is it? Are there guidelines on this kind of offtopicness, or how to call attention to it?

I have no issue with pertinent advice, or calling attention to problems with the question that might go beyond the scope of just answering it. I'm referring to when the answerer goes to some length on their view of best practice (unless that was what was asked about).

Comment: Do you have an example question for that?

Comment: If the lecture makes it a bad answer, simply downvote. If it's valuable information however, I don't really see what the problem is.

Comment: Sometimes it's a good thing. I mean, if OP uses tool, technique or function that's obsolete, informing him it's a bad idea along with answering his problem sounds reasonable. It's a way to avoid next questions. It's like shouting "don't step on that landmine" when someone asks if closest road is in that direction ;)

Comment: Are you saying that if we see something that is a bad practice - say something that is a security vulnerability, people should say **nothing**?

Comment: So what about that example @juergend asked for?

Comment: @Oded I've no problem with sound advice, well delivered.  Lecturing is something different, and normally gives off a very strong whiff of ego. It's not the same thing as saying something is bad practice, or saying something is usually or often considered bad practice. It's lecturing - "I know; you don't; shut up and listen to me" - that I have a specific problem with, not good advice well delivered. Even the soundest argument will rarely hit its mark when delivered in the wrong tone.

Comment: I have yet to see the kind of behavior you describe.

Comment: @slhck perhaps I have been unlucky then. I'm not going to cite an isolated example, since I'm sure that will lead to a micro discussion of the substantive points made in the answer, where my problem is actually with the tone.

Comment: I'm guessing from the comments that the answer to my question is "Yes, lecturing is OK on stackoverflow". I'm happy to leave it at that. You can stop downvoting me now.

Comment: **my problem is actually with the tone.** - Well, yes, it's your problem if you are trying to hear tone on a written medium. We are from all corners of our lovely sphere called Earth, with different language skills, raised in different cultures. What you find a bad tone possibly was perfectly neutral statement to whoever wrote it. **Assuming you know emotions behind an answer or comment is usually not OK**.

Comment: @user1681572: If you're not willing to provide *any* examples, how can we tell whether you're being oversensitive or raising a legitimate concern? A discussion of the *tone* of specific examples would be useful, even if a discussion on the correctness of the specific points wouldn't.

Comment: @Molot you've provided a good example of "tone". Or was yours a "perfectly neutral statement"?

Comment: @user1681572 You are offended by Molots comment? If so I think in many cases it may be impossible to answer your questions without offending you

Comment: @user1681572, I find Mołot's statement to be perfectly neutral, honestly. Unless you have a problem with bold type?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I used bold to highlight most important parts of comment that turned out longer than I wanted it to. Nothing more behind it. Sorry if I offended OP, I didn't meant to. But if I provided example, maybe it's a good thing?

Comment: @Richard Did I say I was offended?

Comment: You know what offends me @FrédéricHamidi? Accented e-s in usernames!

Comment: @user1681572 In that case could you explain what you ment by "you've provided a good example of "tone". Or was yours a "perfectly neutral statement"?"? As I am now confused

Comment: @Bart, apologies, didn't really have a choice in the matter ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi How is to say "We are from all corners of our lovely sphere called Earth, with different language skills, raised in different cultures" neutral, as though it is something I wouldn't already be aware of? And how is it pertinent?

Comment: @user1681572 Its pertinent because people from different cultures have different ideas about what is polite (some things make obvious sense and are universal, some are purely cultural). Additionally someone with english as a second language may sound ruder than they are; "require" instead of "request" etc etc

Comment: @user1681572 Additionally in this case you seem to have been offended by a comment written in (what seems to me) a whimsical style. Which only goes to drive home the point

Comment: @RichardTingle Why are you inventing this offence that you seem to think I have taken?

Comment: @RichardTingle what does "whimsical" means? If I understand that you are talking about my comment, I'd love to know as I can't figure out how to apply google translate results for it to what I said. But oh well, that's probably due to my limited language skill.

Comment: @RichardTingle maybe these people I think are lecturing are actually being whimsical.. my mistake..

Comment: @Mołot "playfully quaint or fanciful, especially in an appealing and amusing way"

Comment: @RichardTingle Oh. OK. Thank you. That's NOT what Google Translate told me :P

Comment: @RichardTingle Not all true statements are neutral. If they are things that intelligent people might be expected already to know, they are condescending.

Comment: @user1681572 I hate that attitude, it's the same reason most academic text books don't make sense. Because everyone assumes everything is obvious and shouldn't be explained to us lesser mortals

Comment: @user1681572 Also remember answers aren't for you, they're for everyone. So explaining "basic" things is very helpful and should be encouraged

Comment: @RichardTingle What you say makes no sense at all.

Comment: @user1681572 How so? Assume I won't be offended by having it explained to me

Comment: @RichardTingle "it's the same reason most academic text books don't make sense. Because everyone assumes everything is obvious and shouldn't be explained to us lesser mortals". Academic textbooks mostly do make sense, and obviously for very good practical reasons have to assume prior knowledge, which is clear, and nothing to do with anything I said. There is all the difference in the world between that kind of prior knowledge and what intelligent people might be expected to know, e.g. that people come from different cultures.

Comment: @user1681572 Obviously you get to the point where you just can't put more information in without it becoming silly. My point is that ommiting information for fear that including it would offend people is an extremely unhelpful attitude for people learning the subject. If we could have an example though this might go somewhere.

Comment: Ok, so how would you have phrased Molots comment?

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem was unproven for 358 years as Fermat found proof too big and yet too trivial to even write it down ;) Quite an argument for @RichardTingle claim, isn't it? :D

Comment: @RichardTingle I'll say again - it's nothing to do with offending people. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @user1681572 Ok, found Molot's tone unacceptable?

Comment: I have the strong feeling we're running around in circles here, guys.

Comment: @RichardTingle Why do you think I found Molot's tone unacceptable? I was merely saying it was an example of tone.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm enclined to agree, I'm voting to close until an example or clearer definition is provided

Comment: Related: [Is "don't do it" a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What exactly your definition of lecturing is, is still somewhat unclear. But I get the idea it might have more to do with tone than content.

In terms of content, lecturing might not be bad. If I would see a user ask something, and approach the problem in an (in my opinion) incorrect or less than ideal manner, I might leave an answer that perhaps somewhat strays from the desired path, but would end up being a better solution. If that is lecturing, I don't have a problem with it. Of course, if the answer has no relation whatsoever to the question asked, then I'd vote as I see fit.

If lecturing would mean writing an answer in such a way that it comes across as arrogant, that's of course not all that great. But well, arrogance I can shrug off thinking "I hope you feel good about yourself". If your answer is essentially correct, I'd let it slide, or at the most I would not upvote. Perhaps I'd attempt an edit, if I feel it would not be too invasive, but that's as far as I'd take it.

If lecturing however implies intolerable rudeness or behaviour that violates "be nice", I might downvote, or in extreme cases even flag.

So I guess the answer would be "it depends".

Comment: Please don't forget apparent rudeness due to lack of language skills. Some of us sounds rude or arrogant not because we want to, but because we don't know gentler words. Flags and downvotes will not help it. Edits and comments can.

Comment: It works both ways @Mołot. When writing something, try to think of those who will read it. You might write something with the best intentions, [yet it might not interpreted as such](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191089/why-do-we-let-hostile-users-dictate-the-perception-of-stack-overflow#comment593788_191089), so perhaps you'll have to be a bit more subtle. And if you read something somewhat rude, that might not always be what the author intended. Give and take.

Comment: I do, I have 14k network rep and never got banned or even mailed by mods. But still it was problematic sometimes. Not to look far, [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209277/should-lecturing-be-allowed/209279?noredirect=1#comment669316_209277) turned out to be problematic for one user, and perfectly OK for some (at least 4). And I needed explanation from Richard Tingle to start to understand how it might be seen as something bad. So, you know. All I want to say is: **if someone appears rude but is not a native speaker, give him a hand, not a kick**.

Comment: @Molot If you think your comment was problematic for me, it wasn't, and I don't see why you thought it was. Well done for having such a high reputation!

Comment: Beginning an answer along the lines of "Well, for a start you shouldn't have done it like that at all.." which I've seen often, is a problem, because it discourages the questioner, in the same way as a teacher calling a pupil stupid. Answering the question asked, then possibly adding 'A better approach might be ... because..' is the form I would encourage.

Comment: Not if their approach is something that shouldn't be done in the first place

Comment: @user1681572: The problem is that if you answer the question as written, the "a better approach might be" is often completely ignored. In the case of something like "Why doesn't my query using SQL concatenation work?" where the answer is: "Don't do that - it's a SQL injection attack waiting to happen. Use parameterized SQL instead, like this..." it's *really important* that the OP changes their course. It's more important than getting them past the immediate hurdle with their insecure code.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agree subject to context. If the code's a simple snippet to illustrate the question, then no. If it's real code that's going to find its way into a production system, then yes. If it's not clear, then "If this code is destined for a production system, you should be aware that it's vulnerable to an injection attack - <reference to discussion>". They may care, they may not. I have seen so much subjective stuff cited as fact on SO that I don't like the idea that it's where people come to learn to code.

Comment: @user1681572: If the OP is presenting non-representative code which is dangerous and hasn't said so, that's their own fault IMO. One of the major problems on SO is when people ask a question containing an error, then when the error is pointed out to them they say "Well that's not in my real code, so the problem is elsewhere..." That's why providing a short but complete program demonstrating the problem you're actually interested in is so important. Personally, I'd rather over-educate when it comes to dangerous holes like SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @JonSkeet agree that the OP has some responsibility for the quality of the answer, but the problem is that such warnings are only helpful if they are correct and properly qualified. Otherwise they can be the opposite. I can see that the consensus is against me, but I'm unpersuaded. The advantages of sticking closely to the topic and disadvantages of opinion posted as fact weigh heavier imo.

Comment: @user1681572: If they're incorrect or unhelpful, then they should be downvoted - but then you're complaining about the *content* rather than the *tone*. Again, if you'd provided concrete examples of where you think the answer was unhelpful, it would have been easier for us to agree or disagree. Are there *some* inappropriately-worded answers? Of course. Is it always a bad idea to tell people when they're doing something stupid? Nope.

Comment: @JonSkeet the trouble is, they are often upvoted. Content vs tone.. hmm I think that opinion (or consensus, or orthodoxy) posted as fact covers both. 'Don't do that' is tone, and lecturing. 'This leaves you open to an SQL injection attack' is content, and not.

Comment: @JonSkeet an issue, of course, being that downvoting costs reputation but upvoting doesn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's almost always a bad idea to tell someone they're doing something stupid by saying "You're stupid", which can be said in many ways.

Comment: @user1681572: Oh noes, a single point of rep lost! Really not an issue most of the time. If you want to express your disapproval without losing any rep, post a comment. (Ideally, do both.) Again, I don't see this a a regular problem. If they're being upvoted, that suggests the community views the response as helpful - which means it probably *is* correct.

Comment: @user1681572: That's why I didn't say "tell people they're stupid" - I said to tell people *when they're doing something stupid* which isn't the same thing at all. Again, without showing any examples, it's very hard to know whether or not we actually agree - except that I don't believe it's a significant problem on SO, on the posts I've seen.

Comment: If no one else thinks this is an interesting or useful question, perhaps it can be removed.

Comment: No it can't @user1681572. It has positively scored answers.

Comment: @user1681572 No one else thinks it's useful **without an example**

Answer (score 4):

What you call "lecturing" is all likelihood an attempt by the answerer to avoid having to write the same answer to the next hundred questions about the same topic, but worded differently.  So they can simply refer to that answer when the question comes up again.

There are certainly ways to make that smoother, the possibly best example of that is [bobince's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17034) to the *eternal* question "How to parse HTML with regex?"  You probably think it was a funny answer instead of a lecture, but it certainly was written in *desperation* with the unstoppable glut of very similar questions.

Lecturing is an entirely legitimate way to answer a question and avoid desperation.  If you don't like the tone then just use your right to vote to express your discontent.