# Many downvotes for no reason

Tags: support, stack-overflow, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)
>   [Serial downvoting — is it detected, and what is the threshold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108029/serial-downvoting-is-it-detected-and-what-is-the-threshold)
>   [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

I think I upset some user for some reason, because he seems to be on a downvote rampage on my StackOverflow account. I don't think it's fair at all for this to happen and he should, at least, provide a reason for it. I don't even know how to find out who he is to ask him what are his motives.

Please advise.

Comment: Yeah -58 points due to likely one dude is pretty lame!

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108029/serial-downvoting-is-it-detected-and-what-is-the-threshold

Comment: **Don't panic!** ;) There's an automated script that runs daily that handles serial voting. The downvotes will be removed next time it runs...

Comment: Actually [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting) is probably better

Comment: @All: Phew! Thanks for the feedback. I rushed to ask for support instead of searching for an answer, since this hasn't happened before to me.

Comment: @MihaiTodor No worries, 29 downvotes can be scary... _If_ they don't get removed in 24h, send Stack Exchange an email with a link to your profile, they can invalidate the downvotes by hand. 99% of the time the script works flawlessly, but there are some extremely nasty people out there that go at great lengths when it comes to revenge downvoting, creating different accounts just to downvote, so they won't get caught - and they get caught every time ;P

Comment: Thanks! I will keep an eye on it :)

Comment: We'll deal with the culprit, so all that's left for you to do is wait for the script to reverse the votes.