# How one can procedurally get in direct contact with a supervisor to ask for an investigation and perceived danger is suspected?

Tags: support, abuse

I cannot find anywhere I wish to get assistance with getting an investigation into the repeated follow to down vote me unfairly and then insult me as well as make fun of my disability making this unacceptable, violations abuse and I need a complaint immediately filed.  Can you help?

Comment: Flag the post or comment for moderator attention and explain your situation.  Private issues cannot be discussed here.

Comment: I can't flag a post with enough time before this person makes changes editing comments and deleting his old posts adding new ones, making me lose my entire complaint...i can't seem to call immediate attention..

Comment: Moderator flags can only be cleared by a moderator, so deleting a post will do nothing.  In which case, only flag a post.

Comment: Make screenshots.

Comment: thanks for the assistance, I can't have this person keep tagging me because edits get made and my post looks like it got not formatted well, additionally i know its a hitjob for no reason... I need to file a complaint due to TOS violations including discrimination and other ethics

Comment: if you are referring to you answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/1113602/208825) while there are some comments i do believe are missing i can agree with 2 of Ramhound's comments that i can read. first was that you did indeed in a way tell the asker to "google it themselves" buy saying the links are in google but you still do not provide them, second is that the link that you claim is HP Support goes to http://hp.support.com/ which then redirects to https://www.support.com/pc-support/ however the hp support website i am aware of is neither of those but http://support.hp.com/us-en

Comment: thats the one friend.  he made that comment 30 minutes after my complaint to stop it and i'm filing complaint.  I dont care about that because I had my post force pushed without able to read it.  This happened when I flagged posts for some reason i guess a mod allows it to kill the post i wrote before posting (timeout) or force push it  I'm not worried about his votes after that.  I expected him to downvote after saying stop talking to me , you violated TOS, i'm filing compaints....I can't get that out in a flag post to a mod]

Comment: Perhaps review http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172183/what-checks-are-in-place-to-prevent-high-rep-users-and-mods-from-abusing-their-p

Comment: *scratches head*... Don't see why this one should be off-topic. A dupe maybe, buy why off-topic? It isn't like the procedure to complain/ask assistance about a possible user rude behavior changes based on the site, so unless this degenerate in a rant, I would prefer to close as dupe instead.

Comment: Anyway, the link for contacting the Stack Exchange staff is this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact. Alternatively, you could try to ask [Jon Ericson](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson), he has always been ready to lend an hand when needed in the past. Just please, before contacting the staff directly ensure the issue is real and not just due to some miss-understanding you could have worked out in some other way.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist dupe it is indeed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was searching for the most appropriate one, but you preceded me.

Comment: I'd note, I deleted that post, not him, and he made no reference to your disability - I did tell him to drop it and would have thrown him a suspension if I'd found *any* references to disability - which I did not. http://superuser.com/a/1113602/10165 is the question, and this is one of *many* deleted answers. I *will* chew out, or otherwise handle any user who's abusive towards others. I didn't see it.

Comment: Just to note I changed the qquestion title.   I did not name any names because i wanted to not have to explain  or show the evidence and professional affidavit fro MD and  certified education instructor for debunking what the words are harmful and define any claim i hhave

Comment: This is still a duplicate. If not of what I selected, of [this other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104375/what-is-the-best-way-to-contact-a-moderator-about-a-user). Flagging is still the best option to contact moderators, you can't and should not contact a specfic moderator in private. So all in all, can't see any reason to reopen this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard do I need to worry about this claim of "perceived danger" the author is claiming now?  I assume my identity, won't be revealed for any reason associated , connected to such a baseless claim?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek see above

Comment: @Ramhound not sure what you mean. If you mean that you are the one the author of this question is complaining about then no, nobody is going to reveal your identity, just look into it (i.e. a moderator) and if you indeed made something against the rules, take measures such as warning you, and if needed suspending you, as the site moderator commented here as well. (So far, like he said, he found no such thing though.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good to hear, the wordage the author of this question is using has specific meaning most of the time, I might still ask a CM to step in, dont like being pulled through the mud, connected to the phrase like "perceived danger".  Thanks for the response.  I am indeed the user the author is talking about, the confirmation is in the comment section, so there is no reason to say otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

Use a custom flag on a post (not a comment) and explain the problem.  Even if posts are deleted, custom flags remain for moderators to deal with.

Once you do this, check your [flagging history](https://superuser.com/users/flag-summary/111696) for a response.  You'll at least see whether the flag was marked helpful or declined, and if declined there will be a further message from the moderators.  Read it.  (This does not generate a notification, so you'll just have to keep checking in.)

If you are still not satisfied, you can use the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page on the site to submit a request to SE staff.

Comment: Thank you so much, and I appreciate the careful attention that you and the others were paying towards me and I hope that I can get any reply because I, -here to help only, Just witnessed something that hurts, but will not tolerate discriminating and using derogatory language that I will disclose elsewhere but there is no place for a person to make fun of you and then go to mock a disability here.

Comment: Monica I apologize and just about all the responding was using the android mobile app where it has caused me to prematurely have posts made and the lack of full functionality which has unfortunately made my reputation drop dramatically as moderators weren't able to see any information about my flagging reason,  and they drop my score without the time i had to reply.   Forgive the assumption i could work efficiently and more with this app however i cant make any reputation positive from any bug that may cause short coming